# Selected dimensions convert to div table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reverse-engineering, css-tables

Can anyone help me reverse engineer [this](https://divtable.com/generator/) or [this](https://html-cleaner.com/html-table-generator/) page? Where the user selects the dimensions via a grid system. Then the amount of selected boxes gets converted into div's, in the same dimensions.

Or does anyone recommend and a JavaScript, if so which one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have two issues here, one is selecting and one is generating. Generating is simple:

**Notice**: This is done quick and dirty; innerHtml should not be used, Ping me if you'd like to see it more polished :)
https://jsfiddle.net/ynfb3Lh2/9/

```
<div id="selection">
</div>
<div id="target">
</div>
<pre id="text">
</pre>

<script>
  // Prepare our targets
  const selectionContainer = document.getElementById("selection");
  const targetContainer = document.getElementById("target");
  const textContainer = document.getElementById("text");

  // rows: How many rows to generate?
  // cols: How many cols to generate?
  // [_insertCallback]: should we insert callback? 
  // [_targetContainer]: where should we place created divs?
  // [_textContainer]: sWhere should we write our HTML as plain text? 
  function generateDiv(rows, columns, _insertCallback, _targetContainer, _textContainer) {
    // Create our wrapping elements
    const table = document.createElement("table");
    const tbody = document.createElement("tbody");

    for (let r = 0; r < rows; ++r) {
      // Each row is created here...
      const tr = document.createElement("tr");

      for (let c = 0; c < columns; ++c) {
        const td = document.createElement("td");
        td.text = "&nbsp;"
        // if callback is defined, and we have a target - allow us to generate new table on each click
        if (_insertCallback && _targetContainer) {
          td.onclick = () => generateDiv(r + 1, c + 1, false, _targetContainer, _textContainer)
        }

        tr.appendChild(td)
      }


      // ... and added here
      tbody.appendChild(tr)
    }

    table.appendChild(tbody)

    if (_targetContainer && !_insertCallback ) {
      _targetContainer.innerHTML = '';
      _targetContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
    if (_textContainer && !_insertCallback ) {
      _textContainer.innerHTML = table.outerHTML
      .replace(/td><\//gi, "td>&amp;nbsp;</")
      .replace(/</gi, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/gi, ">\n");
    }

    return table;
  }

  selectionContainer.appendChild(generateDiv(10, 10, true, targetContainer, textContainer));

</script>
```

and similarily, making a selectable table is done via similar function that adds row and col information to each cell. Then, a mouseClick event on table will read the rows and cols and pass to the generation code.

Comment: How can I make the function that adds the row and col, and how do i highlight them? I'm quite new at this, ty!

Comment: Btw if you havent noticed, another revision is up: https://jsfiddle.net/ynfb3Lh2/9/